# How can I get type safety for returned functions in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, type-safety

This TypeScript compiles fine:

```
abstract class Animal {
    /*
    Any extension of Animal MUST have a function which returns
    another function that has exactly the signature (string): void
     */
    abstract getPlayBehavior(): (toy: string) => void;
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    /*
    Clearly does not have a function which returns a function
    that has the correct signature. This function returns a function with
    the signature (void) : void
    */
    getPlayBehavior() {
        return () => {
            console.log(`Play with toy_var_would_go_here!`);
        };
    }
}

class Program {
    static main() {
        let cat: Animal = new Cat();
        cat.getPlayBehavior()("Toy");
    }
}

Program.main();
```

I am expecting an error because the Cat class definitely does not implement the abstract Animal class *properly*. I expect that the Cat class must have a function which returns another function of the exact signature specified in the abstract Animal class.

Running the code, I get:

```
> node index.js
> Play with toy_var_would_go_here!
```

Is there anything I can do to make sure the compiler enforces this kind of policy?

Comment: In JavaScript, a nullary function _is_ a unary function. The extra arguments passed are simply ignored. This is common in, say, event handling. So your function is of the correct signature.

Comment: @FengyangWang: I don't disagree, except to say that TypeScript does a lot of things that do not get emitted as JavaScript only so that type safety is enforced. I'm just curious if I can find a way to enforce this type safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting an error because in javascript/typescript you're not forced to declare the arguments if you don't want to use them, as long as there's no contradiction.

For example, the signature of the [Array.forEach](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L1221) is:

```
forEach(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
```

But this will compile just fine:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3];
a.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

And that's a good thing, it would have been horrible if I had to have all arguments even if I don't use them.
The same goes here:

```
type MyFn = (s: string) => void;
let fn: MyFn = () => console.log("hey");
```

If I don't need to use the string argument then I can neglect it, or I can even do:

```
let fn: MyFn = () => console.log(arguments);
```

If you'll change the signature of the function that you return in `Cat.getPlayBehavior` to something that contradicts the definition in `Animal` then you'll get an error:

```
class Cat extends Animal {
    getPlayBehavior() {
        return (n: number) => {
            console.log(`Play with toy_var_would_go_here!`);
        };
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Class 'Cat' incorrectly extends base class 'Animal'.
  Types of property 'getPlayBehavior' are incompatible.
    Type '() => (n: number) => void' is not assignable to type '() => (toy: string) => void'.
      Type '(n: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(toy: string) => void'.
        Types of parameters 'n' and 'toy' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Comment: I personally do not find it horrible to strictly require functions be defined explicitly according to their base class/interface. For example, if a function has an optional parameter(s) those can be defined explicitly as optional. If this is not a good default, then something like strict {} blocks would be useful to those developers who would be more comfortable with explicitly and strictly defined types.

Comment: Well, that's how javascript works, and typescript also permits it. If the passed function doesn't need to use the arguments then it just don't include them in the signature. As I said, that works as long as there's no contradiction. An optional parameter means something else, it means that it may or may not be passed, but here you're saying that you don't care if that param is passed or not, you just don't need it.

Comment: Hmm, Ok. It sounds like what I'm looking for out of TypeScript does not currently exist and my thoughts would be better put as a suggestion on their site. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome to convey it to the typescript guys, but I'm pretty sure that this is by design, and it makes sense.  The type safety works well here, as you can't define a signature that receives something else other than one string. If this function will need this string it will add the param, but if not then the function still satisfies the type requirement.

Answer (score 1):

> I am expecting an error because the Cat class definitely does not implement the abstract Animal class properly

Because of type compatability. A function (say `foo`) that doesn't take any parameter is assignable to a function (say `bar`) that does take a parameter.

Reason: There is no usage of `bar` where all the information needed for `foo` to function will be absent.

## More

This is also covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-compatibility.html#number-of-arguments

Comment: Generally, abstractions and interfaces are contractual agreements. Implementations follow them explicitly to the letter of how those interfaces/abstractions are defined. If many methods start appearing that do not need a variable from the function in an interface, the design should maybe be considered. I'm looking for a way to impose this strict implementation.